# How to display color picker on button click, and on select of particular color i want to get a hex code of that color?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, color-picker

which is the best cocoapod of color pickets for ios application?

I am trying to implement `DRColorPickerWheelView` by installing cocoapods in my sample application, next I want to get the  `RGB` value. How to get that - Please do help.

I am implementing as following,
correct me if I am wrong.

```
import UIKit

import DRColorPicker

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let img = UIImageView()
        img.image = DRColorPickerImage("colormap")
        img.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 90, width: 330, height: 300)

        view.addSubview(img)

        let v = DRColorPickerWheelView()
        v.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 40, width: 350, height: 400)

        view.addSubview(v)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to get selected UIColor?

Comment: https://github.com/jjxtra/DRColorPicker/blob/master/Pod/Classes/DRColorPicker%2BUIColor.m , according to this category, you can use `let str = yourSelectedColorVariable.hexStringFromColor`

Comment: yeah Done. its worked.. thanks much 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code:

```
let str = yourSelectedColorVariable.hexStringFromColor
```

This category defined at: [DRColorPicker](https://github.com/jjxtra/DRColorPicker/blob/master/Pod/Classes/DRColorPicker%2BUIColor.m)